# Setting default of one function as default of another function

Tags: r, function, scoping

I want to understand if setting a function as the default to another function has caused anyone issues?  Is this clearly not best practice?

```
add_this <- function(a = 1, b = 2){
  a + b
}

print_what_we_added <- function(the_sum = add_this()){
  paste0("the sum of what we added is ", the_sum)
}

print_what_we_added()
print_what_we_added(5)
```

Comment: There is always a little bit of ambiguity with default values of function arguments. For *good* and for *bad*. Since we can also do things like `print_what_we_added(add_this(3, 5))` IMHO your code *could* be ok. But I think it really depends on your real problem and code..

Comment: It should be fine so long as you take care to pass the output of the function ( function call with parenthesis:`add_this()` ) and not the function itself :  `add_this` , which would pass the function pointer instead. I've seen several functions calling others to set defaults.